# Deploying a vaadin app to tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, vaadin

I'm trying to learn Java and want to write a basic webapp using Vaadin (and Maven) in Eclipse.
I have a single java file which should create a window with a single panel.
I have a tomcat server setup, but when I try and run my project on that I can't get past this error:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet

I have "vaadin-server-7.6.4.jar" installed in my Maven dependencies folder, so I am guessing I haven't set the paths correctly in the web.xml (or pom.xml?).
Any ideas where I should start troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the jar is present in the Classpath. Either that jar should be inside the lib folder of Tomcat installation directory or it should be packaged in the lib folder of the web app.

Comment: thanks for your help, that seems to have solved that problem! There was a file called "vaadin-server-7.6.4.pom.lastUpdated" so I deleted that and copied over the "vaadin-server-7.6.4.jar".